# How setup current time zone on server in php and mysqli

Tags: time, installation, zone

I am trying this php funtion "date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata")" to set time zone, but inserting some other time in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your setting first by: echo date_default_timezone_get();

Comment: i have tried, its showing "Asia/Kolkata" @Nguyen Thanh Hung

Comment: Could you show some lines of you PHP code when you try inserting time to mysqli

Comment: on local server date and time is correct but on host server its not.@Nguyen Thanh Hung

Comment: actually i'm using shared server, i there any option to change timezone using php

Comment: Try to set timezone in php code, such as: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
echo date("y-m-d H:i:s");
```